# join in active record codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, activerecord

Would you like to help me? How to change this sql query to active record in codeigniter

```
LEFT JOIN MGMETADATA.services d ON d.protocol = e.protocol and d.port = e.s_port
```

Thanks,

Comment: is it your full query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tableE');
$this->db->join('tableD','tableD.protocol=tableE.protocol and tableD.port=tableE.s_port','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

i hope this can help  you

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("*")
         ->join("MGMETADATA.services as d","d.protocol = e.protocol","left")
         ->where("d.port = e.s_port")
         ->get("tablename e")
         ->result(); //for json format
```

note: dont use "*" for selecting all columns, please use individual column name to retrieve.